# What is the correct format for $value for updating Google Map field with update_field in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, google-maps

I’m working to update the Google map field via an external form, but I haven’t been able to figure out the correct format. I currently have something similar to this:

```
$value = array(
  "address" => $address,
 "lat" => '24.739412360143447',
 "lng" =>'101.76182085000005');

update_post_meta($post_id,'google_map',$value);
```

what is the correct format for updating **Advance custom fields** of Google Maps?

Answer (score 1):

try this one , hopefully will work :)

```
$field_name = "field_53bdd058c84a8";
$value = array("address" => $address, "lat" => $lat, "lng" => $lng, "zoom" => $zoom);
update_field($field_name, $value, $this_ID);
```

Comment: I try this resolution a lot of time, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You might try substituting 'coordinates' for 'google_map':

```
$value = array("address" => $address, "lat" => '24.739412360143447', "lng" =>'101.76182085000005');
update_post_meta($post_id, 'coordinates', $value);
```

Someone on [this page](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/update-google-map-field/) had a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution suggested by @felix works form me. Check that `$lat`, `$lng` and `$zoom` are integer. So this should work:

```php
$field = array(
    "address" => "Piazza del Colosseo, 1, 00184 Roma RM, Italia",
    "lat"     => 41.89021020000001,
    "lng"     => 12.4922309,
    "zoom"    => 7
);
update_field($field_name, $field, $id);
```